# spork LoadError on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

Here's the complete error.  Any ideas on how to resolve this. I found nothing on google.  I'm running Ubuntu Linux on VirtualBox.

```
Using RSpec, Unknown
cannot load such file -- magazine/magazine_slave (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/magazine.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:73:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: my recommendation - don't use spork.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with my ubuntu system. The problem is in gems files permissions they  not readable for users except for the owner. To solve this, change permissions of files to 0644 or a+r, like this:

```
$ chmod -v 644 files/myfile.txt
mode  of  `files/myfile.txt'  changed  to  0644  (rw-r--r--)
```

You may use **sudo** to get permission. For more operation, visit  http://help.unc.edu/help/how-to-use-unix-and-linux-file-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Last time I edit the answer above, but I still can not solve the problem.

Then I did some search, finally I solved it.

According to the solution,  it seems that the installed gem does not put enough permissions to the executable.

I used this: `gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'`

Solutions: [a gist on github](https://gist.github.com/zunda/5328483)